# Installing VisualSVN when Apache is already installed

Tags: apache, visualsvn-server

Is there any way I can install VisualSVN Server not installing Apache?

The thing is that I already have Apache installed in the same server, so I want VisualSVN Server to use that Apache installation.

By the way: I was told that VisualSVN Server is the best (easyest) alternative for installing SVN in Windows Server. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just install svnserve (a standalone subversion server) from the binaries at collabnet. It's simpler than integrating subversion with apache.